# why is X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy only for core levels?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I'm not sure why we can't get information from an atom, by looking at emitted electrons from the valence level. My book writes it is mainly a tool only for deep core levels.

Why can't we use characteristic binding energies at the valence level instead of binding energies at the core level?

Comment: Hint: what kinds of energies are necessary to get X-ray photons, and how does that energy compare to the differences between valence level energies?

Comment: could you please give more details about what book you are referring to.

Comment: @probably_someone  The x-ray photons have too high energy I think. But Couldn't you use UV light to emit the electrons, and obtain information about the atom?

Comment: @lakehal It's surface science - an introduction by K. Oura et al.  Actually they explain why but I don't understand it

Comment: @PernkDernets Then wouldn't it be UV photoelectron spectroscopy? (see e.g. https://xpssimplified.com/UPS.php)

Comment: @probably_someone you are right, I just it wasn't a thing due to noise. But it must be then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of practicality.

Valence level spectroscopy with visible/uv light is used also. We can inspect with our own eyes the existence of clorophyll (green) or Iron oxides (orange). However there is a lot of noise and the valence electrons energy depend on the chemical bond, that is, are different for pure Iron or Iron oxides. 
Thus, UV/visible/infrared spectroscopy is good to inspect molecules.

With X ray, you look at inner electrons, thus:

- the signal is cleaner (higher energy, absent in the background)
- the signal is quite independent of the chemical bonds, because you are exciting deep electrons, so you can measure how much Iron there is, independently on if it is oxide or sulfide state.

Comment: The core levels DO show you chemical shifts.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess it's hard to do with materials because of the bonds? causing an energy band. Then the energy levels are no longer distinct for an atom?